# avoid delete document from solr on dataimport

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am trying to Add 300 Million record in Solr but something Wrong happen .

after 200 million Solr Start Delete from Document.

When I add 200 million Record from Oracle to Solr every thing work good .

in pic below

*max Doc* = 215077886

*Num Docs*:200979747

*Deleted Docs*:14098139

**Why Solr Delete 14098139** I try Many Times But the same result come

So my Problem that there is an configuration to Avoid Delete and I can't know it

All Configuration Files in this Link :
[Conf files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByYjroSu3eoBckFidnJQd0J3UEU?usp=sharing)

My Server Ram 32 G

HD : 2 Tera

**Edit**

*I Solve The Problem I found duplicate uniqueKeys*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the documents are being deleted and not overwritten because of duplicate uniqueKeys or something like that? Does the Solr log say anything (perhaps the import process is running out of memory and not indexing any further)? Have you tried doing the import in smaller batches?

Comment: Thanks , I found problem in duplicate uniqueKeys
and every thing is ok now

Answer (score 1):

Usually these issues are caused by duplicate `uniqueKeys`, since the full import process doesn't deleted documents by itself (you can ask it to clean out the index, but that's an explicit request, or use a separate delete query to remove entries that has been deleted as part of a delta query).

Make sure that the documents used actually are unique for the column set as the `uniqueKey` column. If a document imported later has the same uniqueKey as a previous document, the new document will overwrite the old one (i.e. an add and a delete), resulting in counts in the `deleted` column.